# How to make sure payment card is completely authorized for off-session charges?

Tags: stripe-payments

My goal is setting up automatic subscription payments with Stripe.

Upon reading [this Stripe guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents#increasing-success-rate-by-specifying-usage), I got the impression that setting `usage` to `off_session` would be enough to completely authorize the card for off-session/subscription charges. However, then I ran into the `confirm` property in the [SetupIntent api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-confirm), which says:

> Set to true to attempt to confirm this SetupIntent immediately. This
> parameter defaults to false. If the payment method attached is a card,
> a return_url may be provided in case additional authentication is
> required.

I just don't get it. What sort of confirmation is this? Do I need to set this to `true`? How does it affect `ussage`?

Answer (score 0):

The confirmation of a PaymentIntent or SetupIntent is essentially the user authorizing that the payment can be made. Confirmation can be attempted both server side and client side which is why this setting exists and the APIs to confirm server side exist also. When building this integration though, confirmation should take place client side using Stripe.js as the user is on session and can satisfy SCA/3DS requirements [1] in the browser.

When creating Subscriptions, a PaymentIntent or SetupIntent (which can be present for trialling Subscriptions) will be created under the hood for you automatically and linked to the first Invoice. That PaymentIntent or SetupIntent will be optimizied for off session payments since it's for a Subscription (which is why it is important to handle potential SCA/3DS authentication with your customer, you'll see this on Step 8 of the linked guide). You then use this PaymentIntent or SetupIntent to guide your customer through the sign up flow and collect a PaymentMethod from them. The rough steps are:

1. Create/retrieve a customer
2. Collect payment information
3. Create a subscription
4. Handle possible payment failure
5. Handle possible SCA/3DS authentication

This flow is outlined in much more detail here [2]. We are currently also working on an improved flow to make this integration simpler. I'll have a colleague reach out to you on that.

Also having said all of that, you can also start Subscriptions through Checkout and this will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you! [3]

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout/fixed-price